# .xctest framework red in Xcode 10.1

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, module, xctest

I have an Xcode project with unit tests.  The product Tests.xctest is red.  The unit tests build and run as debug versions.  Why is it shown in red?

When I look into the products folder and drill down into the packages I see a unix executable Tests for the debug build but not for the release build.  If I set it up in the scheme to build Test for release the build process fails saying failed to load module .

I'm thinking that it maybe is because the release version isn't building, but not sure why that is either.  Why can't it find the module when I set both run and test to release?  It builds and runs for release but tests won't build.

Ideas?

Update: I created a testapp and the problem persists:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a false error. Xcode has gotten this wrong for many years now.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!